# Alternative to matrix inversion?

Tags: matrices, physics, numerical-linear-algebra

In particle physics, we use the Seesaw formula to compute effective masses for neutrinos. It reads
$$ M_\mathrm{eff} = - M_D . M_N^{-1} . M_D^T. $$
As I learned the hard way, Matrix inversion is not very stable numerically.

I have to compute $M_\mathrm{eff}$ numerically, to as high precision as possible. I need both the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors. What alternatives do I have to inverting $M_N$, if the matrix $M_N$ is badly conditioned?

Comment: You might be interested in [this article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/S0036144504443110).